# Is heap related to process in C?

Tags: c, linux

I am reading how malloc() and calloc() are able to allocate memory from heap and I came across a website (http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html) which says that "if you won't free the memory, it will be a memory leak and the memory won't be available for other processes to allocate the memory". But till now I was thinking that heap memory is per process and one process's heap memory is not intermixed with the other process' heap memory. Can any one please let me know whether my understanding is correct?

Comment: On a 32 bit machine an application will get 4 GB of virtual memory. If you keep allocating it and you never free anything you will eventually run out. That's all it's really about.

Comment: it seems you are eating your own piece of cake, but the size of the cake is determined. if you take more, the others have to take less.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Nice example.

Comment: @kadina just hope you understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, heap memory is per process. However, all processes on the same system allocate memory from the same fixed pool, which is limited to the physical memory of your system plus the swap file on virtual memory systems. That is why if one process holds on to the memory that it does not need, it may starve of memory another process on the same computer.

On systems with virtual memory this does not necessarily mean that other processes will run out of memory, though: it means that getting more memory for these other processes would require swapping other processes out of memory. It may be your leaking process or some other process that must be swapped.

On systems without virtual memory management leaking memory in one process would lead to other processes being unable to allocate memory at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that memory has to come from somewhere - physical RAM. So for the lifetime of your process, if you do not free that memory, there is physical RAM allocated to it.

So while the heap does belong to that process, and you aren't "stealing another process's heap", you are still taking physical memory up.

Comment: That is the thing exactly I didn't understand. Heap is per process. So whenever a process is allocated, specific amount of memory is set aside per process and in that specific amount, some memory is allocated for heap. So this total memory is allocated to other processes when the current process finishes it's execution.

Comment: @kadina the heap is dynamically allocated and can grow.

Comment: Actually the initial size of the heap, and the heap allocation strategy, and memory reclamation strategy, are all dependent on the OS. The OS can do what it wants. In practice, I think all modern OS use dynamic allocation (which basically means allocation of memory 'on demand') like @WoodrowBarlow said.

Comment: As mentioned, the heap is allocated *at run time*. So while the memory is "given" to your process, it's the operating system giving it. And you need to give it back, so thta the OS can give it to other processes when they ask fo rit.

Answer (score 1):

You're partially right. When the "leaky" process ends, the memory it claimed is freed and made available to other processes -- but for the duration of its runtime, a leaky process' heap will keep taking up more and more of the available memory, leaving less available for other processes to store their heaps.

A heap is traditionally dynamically allocated and can grow or shrink on demand.

Answer (score 1):

The computer has a certain amount of physical memory (RAM) installed. The Operating System allocates some of that RAM for itself, and tracks the remainder of the RAM. When a process requests memory, the Operating System can allocate memory for that process. Processes cannot access each other's memory space under normal conditions. However, there is a finite amount of total memory available, so when one process mallocs/callocs memory and does not free it, the effect on the system is that there is less memory available for the Operating System to allocate for other processes.